Can the lower (or upper, for that matter) limit of a confidence interval be chosen as a parameter rather than the central value?
To create a counterfactual measure in a study on policy interventions to reduce the effect of outside temperature on mortality in later life, I would like to use the lower bound of confidence intervals obtained via a regression model -they would more closely reflect the 'what-if' question I am interested in, compared to the point estimate.
However I have never come across such a use of one of the bounds of a CI. As in theory any value of the parameter within the CI has the same probability, my intuition is that it'd be fine, but I wonder if there are any statistical complications of choosing one of the limits of a CI of a parameter in further analysis.

An observed confidence interval is an interval estimate of the unknown parameter, so there is nothing wrong in principle from using its lower bound. You just need to describe in more detail how you intend to use it if you want a more-definitive answer.

Re "any value of the parameter within the CI has the same probability:" this is incorrect, suggesting one possible resolution of your question might be a deeper study of what a confidence interval is and how to interpret it.  We have some good threads about this topic here

A bound of a confidence interval is just another statistic, which can be computed from the data. That statistic is itself a random variable (depends on the sample). It has a sampling distribution, etc (whether that sampling distribution is well characterized, to allow tests is a different question). Then you can compute statistics on that random variable (mean, CI, etc...). Now I am not sure what population parameter it relates to? For e.g. a bound of the CI of the mean maybe the mean itself (0 width CI)? Depends on your application;  but that bound is just as good a statistic as any.
